# 2 question about Language Understanding Intelligent Service(LUIS)

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I started learned Language Understanding Intelligent Service(LUIS). I have 2 question.

1. What is Language Understanding Intelligent Service version container use for?
   [image]
2. LUIS version JSON schema has a column which name is "setting", what is that use for?

Answer (score 1):

Versions allow you to build and publish different models. A good practice is to clone the current active model to a different [version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/LUIS/luis-concept-app-iteration) of the app before making changes to the model.

Please follow the below link for how to manage versions in luis.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-how-to-manage-versions

There is a dedicated API in the container to consume the packages exported by versions, which has the signature apps/{appId}/versions/{versionId}. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-container-howto?tabs=v3#export-versioned-apps-package-from-api

Please follow the below link to configure luis docker containers.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-container-configuration

Please refer to [Troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/troubleshooting) to resolve issues related to LUIS functionality.